# Overriding a value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am doing something like:

```
class ProblemAnswersModel extends Backbone.Model {
    parse(response) {
        this.relations = {"interventions" : Backbone.Collection};
        this.set(response);
    }
}
```

But I would like to do:

```
class ProblemAnswersModel extends Backbone.Model {
    this.relations = {"interventions" : Backbone.Collection};
    parse(response) {
        this.set(response);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
class ProblemAnswersModel extends Backbone.Model {
    relations = {"interventions" : Backbone.Collection};
    parse(response) {
        this.set(response);
    }
}
```

But this seems to create a separate variable and not use the underlying backbone one.

Comment: Can you initialize that var in the constructor?

Comment: @elclanrs My constructors are not called by Backbone, a JS lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean `Backbone.Collection` as type but not a constructor function, you should declare `relations` like this:

```
class ProblemAnswersModel extends Backbone.Model {
    relations: { "interventions" : Backbone.Collection };

    parse(response) {
        this.relations = { "interventions" : someBackboneCollectionInstance };
        this.set(response);
    }
}
```

If you want to add relations to prototype:

```
ProblemAnswersModel.prototype.relations = ...
```